# The form in one Component gets submitted by other Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i am having two components CreateCandidate and Technologies in CreateCandidate it requires technologies which are received from Technologies Component so when i pass the technologies to CreateCandidate the form in CreateCandidate gets Submitted here is my code

CreateCandidate:-

```
class CreateCandidate extends Component {
    submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(e.target)
        fetch('/candidate', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(res => console.log(res))
    }
    getTech(e, data) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.state.form['technologies'] = data;
        this.setState({ form: this.state.form });
    }
    render() {
                ...
                        <form className="" onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>

                                        <Technologies getTech={this.getTech.bind(this)} />

                                <button type="submit" id="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" >Create</button>

                        </form>               
    }
}
```

Technology Component:

```
class Technologies extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        technologies: [''],
      };
    }


    handleSubmit(evt){
     this.props.getTech(this.state.technologies);
    }            
    render() {    
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.technologies.map((technology, idx) => (
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={`Technology #${idx + 1}`}
                value={technology[idx]}
                onChange={this.handleTechnologyChange(idx)}
              />
              <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRemoveTechnology(idx)} className="small">-</button>
          ))}
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddTechnology} className="small">Add Technology</button>
          <button>Done</button>
          </div>
      )
    }
  }
  export default Technologies
```

And also in Technologies component when i change the array in state it doesnt get reflected in UI.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Add only relevant code so that SO can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the type of every button to `button` which should not trigger form submitting:

```
render() {    
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.technologies.map((technology, idx) => (
        <div className="shareholder">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={`Technology #${idx + 1}`}
            value={technology[idx]}
            onChange={this.handleTechnologyChange(idx)}
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRemoveTechnology(idx)} className="small">-</button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddTechnology} className="small">Add Technology</button>
      <button type="button">Done</button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

I think that some of the labels like:

```
<label for="technologies" className="cols-sm-2 control-label">Technologies</label>
```

may trigger submit.